# JavaScript results of Prime number test not appearing on screen

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, numbers

I've created a js file that runs in an HTML document that tests if a number is prime or not. The page loads as does the pop-up prompt for input, however, the results are not displaying on the page itself.

See screenshots below:

#### Algorithm

[image: Algorithm]

#### Prompt

[image: Prompt]

#### Page with no result

[image: Page with no result]

I've tried various versions of the .js code to try and get the results to appear between the purpose of the page and the instructions to refresh (Reload) to run again. I've tried code that produces a second pop up which may work but I need it to appear on the screen.

Comment: Check out [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically the bits regarding photos of code being difficult to use, and creating a MWE. I'd recommend adding alerts all the way down to see where things aren't working and if there's an error stopping your code. Also I'd look up how to debug js :) good luck

Comment: As stated above you should add more info in a more readable way. Try adding your HTML code too.

Comment: I would guess there is an error in the developer console. You call checkPrime() when the page loads. i see no where in your code where you bind the function to the button click.

Comment: Add code to questions as text, no an image. It is hard to copy and paste text from an image.

Comment: try opening the javascript console and typing

document.getElementById('demo').textContent = 'test'.

does it update the text? if not, it may give you an error that tells you what's going wrong. You can also try running the page with the console open as espascarello suggests

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.